# Dynamic Textfield not Displaying as3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs6, dynamic-text

I have instantiated in my .as file:

```
private var heroLives:int;

heroLives = 3;
```

then later on in the code I call a function called showHeroLives() which looks like this:

```
public function showheroLives() {
    heroLivesTxt.text = String(heroLives);
    trace(heroLivesTxt.text);
    trace(heroLives);
}
```

I just used trace to make sure that heroLivesTxt gets updated with heroLives.  heroLivesTxt is a dynamic textfield on stage.  If I comment out showHeroLives() so it doesn't try to assign a value, the assigned value (within the stage) of heroLivesTxt shows up.  But once I implement showHeroLives() to update the text through code, it disappears, even though it trace shows that I have updated the text.  Please Help!

Comment: Is the font embedded ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to embed the font. You can embed it via the properties panel of the TextField.